# How to make an object go to alpha 0,5 and back to 1 during one transition?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, transition

I'd like to have smooth effect of fading out and going back to being fully visible. I can set alpha to 0.5 at the beginning and make it go back to 1 during the transition, but that's not the effect that I want. And it has to be done using one transition effect.

Btw, how can I add params to existing transition. Would just `mytransition.params={someparam=2}` work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the easing library to change how the animations works with transitions, so you can manage how the animation works between 2 values. I think you need to use `easing.continuousLoop`

Try to add this to your transition.

Check the easing functions in [easing.* library](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/easing/index.html)

Comment: But that works with the speed of the transition, not the alpha. i had to do that using two other transitions, that was half the time of the normal one, one to get to 0,5 alpha and the other one to get it back to normal. I was asking about using it with one transition because i had a task to use transiton, only once. I made function that would pass params to the transition, and it technically would be using transition only once

Answer (score 0):

Use the `easing.continuousLoop` it's set the alpha to desired value and returns to the previous:

```
transition.to( object, { time=1000, alpha=0, transition=easing.continuousLoop } )
```